# EKS : could not find any suitable subnets for creating the ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-elb, amazon-eks

I am trying to expose a service to the outside world using the `loadBalancer` type service.

For that, i have followed this doc

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-kubernetes-services-cluster/

My `loadbalancer.yaml` looks like this

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

But the load balancer is not creating as expected I am getting the following error

```
Warning  SyncLoadBalancerFailed  8s (x3 over 23s)  service-controller  Error syncing load balancer: failed to ensure load balancer: could not find any suitable subnets for creating the ELB
```

Seems like its because of some issues in the subnet tags to solve,but i have the required tags in my subnets

```
kubernetes.io/cluster/<cluster-name>. owned  
kubernetes.io/role/elb   1
```

But still, I am getting the error `could not find any suitable subnets for creating the ELB`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

By default AWS EKS only attaches load balancers to public subnets. In order to launch it in a private subnet you need to not only label your subnets (which it looks like you did) but also annotate your load balancer-

> service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"

You can find more information [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/load-balancing.html).

Comment: Thanks. saved my day!

Comment: Thanks @tedivm, saved my day too. Somehow this annotation went missing from our service yaml and the external ip would go in pending state.

Comment: Robert Hafner, With EKS upgrade to 1.19, I started getting error
internal-*********-1640942194.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE for an internal load balancer

s kubectl get svc argo-server -n argo        
NAME          TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP                                                                       PORT(S)          AGE
argo-server   LoadBalancer   172.20.200.167   internal-******-1640942194.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com   2746:32212/TCP   30m. 
Have you faced this error with EKS upgrade?

Comment: making `shared` cluster tag instead of owned and using service template from document above helpede me

Answer (score 7):

For people that may reach this question, I have faced the same error, but the problem was really simple.

The tag with key **kubernetes.io/cluster/<cluster-name>** had the wrong cluster name as the automation that deployed it was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

In EKS 1.16, I need internet-facing NLB.

The root cause in EKS is that you haven't selected a public subnet while creating the cluster.

After creating the cluster EKS will not allow to update subnets as of now [here](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/170)

To resolve the issue, I have performed the below steps

1. created a `public subnet` in the same vpc of EKS
2. Attached `IGW` in route tables in new created public subnets
3. Added below `tags` in public subnets
4. `kubernetes.io/cluster/<EKSClusterName>` : `shared`

**Note:** In a 4th step, Replace your EKS cluster name in placeholder `EKSClusterName`

Comment: Nirav , are you able to add a new public subnet and able to deploy the external load balancer ? i created the cluster with only private subnets and as its not allowed to add a new subnet to eks cluster, i am trying to understand if i can create a new public subnet and add tags without adding this subnet to the cluster.

Answer (score 2):

Additional to Robert' answer, you can use the following `kubectl` command for annotating a service;

```
kubectl annotate svc <service-name> service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal="true"
```

Answer (score 2):

**Resolution** This has resolved my issue.

> To identify a cluster's subnets, the Kubernetes Cloud Controller
> Manager (cloud-controller-manager) and AWS Load Balancer Controller
> (aws-load-balancer-controller) query that cluster's subnets by using
> the following tag as a filter:

Choose the appropriate option for tagging your subnets:

**For public and private subnets used by load balancer resources**
Tag all public and private subnets that your cluster uses for load balancer resources with the following key-value pair:

> Key: kubernetes.io/cluster/cluster-name Value: shared

The cluster-name value is for your Amazon EKS cluster. The shared value allows more than one cluster to use the subnet.

**For private subnets used by internal load balancers**
To allow Kubernetes to use your private subnets for internal load balancers, tag all private subnets in your VPC with the following key-value pair:

> Key: kubernetes.io/role/internal-elb Value: 1

**For public subnets used by external load balancers**
To allow Kubernetes to use only tagged subnets for external load balancers, tag all public subnets in your VPC with the following key-value pair:

> Key: kubernetes.io/role/elb Value: 1

Note: Use the preceding tag instead of using a public subnet in each Availability Zone.

reference: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-vpc-subnet-discovery/

Answer (score 1):

Possibly your subnet is not a public one, i.e. accessible from the internet. This will be required for your Loadbalancer to accept traffic from the outside world. In order to make it public, you need to attach an Internet Gateway to your VPC. Check [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html#Add_IGW_Attach_Gateway) for more documentation.

Comment: It's not public one its actually routed through a transit gateway

Answer (score 0):

Usually the issue can be resolved by giving the tag however you can also add the annotations in the service. For eg: if you are exposing the Loadbalancer to the public, you can give the below annotations which will fix the issue.

```
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "elb"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-subnets: "subnet-xxx,subnet-xxx2,subnet-xxx3"
```