# AWS EKS - Reconciler error couldn't auto-discover subnets

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, microservices, amazon-eks

I have deployed node app in aws eks and everything works fine until today. when I deployed latest version today suddenly i got following error.

**couldn't auto-discover subnets: UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation**

`{"level":"error","ts":1622476232.9828672,"logger":"controller","msg":"Reconciler error","controller":"ingress","name":"ingress-srv","namespace":"default","error":"couldn't auto-discover subnets: UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.\n\tstatus code: 403, request id: 0a2968bf-62c2-4a29-a41a-e5defc135e3f"}`

Here is the ingress yaml.

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-srv
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: rabbitmq
          servicePort: 15672
        path: /api/v1/rabbitmq/*
        pathType: Prefix
      - backend:
          serviceName: srv-auth
          servicePort: 4000
        path: /api/v1/users/*
        pathType: Prefix
```

Here is deployment yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: srv-auth-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: srv-auth
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: srv-auth
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: srv-auth
          image: srv-auth //downloadable image
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: srv-auth
spec:
  selector:
    app: srv-auth
  ports:
    - name: srv-auth
      protocol: TCP
      port: 4000
      targetPort: 4000
```

And I found that the related question in stackoverflow but it's not solved my issue [EKS ALB is not to able to auto-discover subnets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66039501/eks-alb-is-not-to-able-to-auto-discover-subnets)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

spend almost 2 day now..

in mycase my policy json was 2.1.3 and i install controller v2.2.0

so maybe this help?

Comment: In my case version key for policy json has date, Can you please provide with the json you used?

Comment: make sure to get the same iam policy for which you are installing the aws loadbalancer controller. For me i update the I am policy and tagged my subnet and vpc.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66039501/eks-alb-is-not-to-able-to-auto-discover-subnets